# how to open project in android studio 1.3.1 version

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4tGL.png)

The second I opened up a new project that there is a problem.
There are problems in photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because gradle cannot download dependancies since it can't connect to internet. First check your internet connection. If you are behind a proxy make sure you configure proxy settings in Android studio.

Comment: i'm connected to internet. how do configure proxy setting in android studio?